# Chefdk berkshelf and vagrant "found a directory cookbooks in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping"

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

**Main questions**
Why doesn't chef see cookbook files in the cookbook path?
How can I solve it?

**Installed already**

- rbenv
- chefdk
- vagrant-berkshelf plugin

**Things I did already**

put this in my .zshrc

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="/opt/chefdk/bin:$PATH"
```

Also did a berks install, and it works!

```
$ berks install
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'app' from source at .
Using app (0.1.0) from source at .
Using apt (2.6.0)
Using java (1.29.0)
Using rbenv (0.7.2) from git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv.git (at v0.7.2)
Using ruby_build (0.8.0) from git://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build.git (at v0.8.0)
```

Vagrant provision (the error):

```
$ vagrant provision
==> default: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Couldn't find Cheffile at ./Cheffile.
==> default: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> default: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> default: Fetching 'app' from source at .
==> default: Using app (0.1.0) from source at .
==> default: Using java (1.29.0)
==> default: Using ruby_build (0.8.0) from git://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build.git (at v0.8.0)
==> default: Using apt (2.6.0)
==> default: Using rbenv (0.7.2) from git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv.git (at v0.7.2)
==> default: Vendoring app (0.1.0) to /Users/****/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20141128-98987-1p3n8pb-default/app
==> default: Vendoring apt (2.6.0) to /Users/****/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20141128-98987-1p3n8pb-default/apt
==> default: Vendoring java (1.29.0) to /Users/****/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20141128-98987-1p3n8pb-default/java
==> default: Vendoring rbenv (0.7.2) to /Users/****/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20141128-98987-1p3n8pb-default/rbenv
==> default: Vendoring ruby_build (0.8.0) to /Users/****/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20141128-98987-1p3n8pb-default/ruby_build
==> default: Chef 12.0.1 Omnibus package is already installed.
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:11+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:11+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.1 ***
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:11+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 10274
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[app]", "recipe[ruby_build]", "recipe[rbenv::user]", "recipe[rbenv::user_install]", "recipe[rbenv::vagrant]"] from CLI options
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[app], recipe[ruby_build], recipe[rbenv::user], recipe[rbenv::user_install], recipe[rbenv::vagrant]]
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [app, ruby_build, rbenv::user, rbenv::user_install, rbenv::vagrant]
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for app-berkshelf
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] WARN: found a directory cookbooks in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] WARN: found a directory tmp in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] WARN: found a directory vagrant-berkshelf in the cookbook path, but it contains no cookbook files. skipping.
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook app not found. If you're loading app from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2014-12-12T13:42:17+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

If you want more info please ask.

update add vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.5.0"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "app-berkshelf"
  config.vm.box = "chef/ubuntu-14.04"

  # Assign this VM to a host-only network IP, allowing you to access it
  # via the IP. Host-only networks can talk to the host machine as well as
  # any other machines on the same network, but cannot be accessed (through this
  # network interface) by any external networks.
  config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"

  # The path to the Berksfile to use with Vagrant Berkshelf
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "./Berksfile"

  # Enabling the Berkshelf plugin. To enable this globally, add this configuration
  # option to your ~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile file
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # get latest chef
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.custom_config_path = "Vagrantfile.chef"

    chef.json = {
      'rbenv' => {
        'user_installs' => [
          { 'user'    => 'vagrant',
            'rubies'  => ['1.9.3-p551'],
            'global'  => '1.9.3-p551',
            'gems'    => {
              '1.9.3' => [
                { 'name' => 'bundler' }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    chef.run_list = [
        'recipe[app]',
        'recipe[ruby_build]',
        'recipe[rbenv::user]',
        'recipe[rbenv::user_install]',
        'recipe[rbenv::vagrant]'
    ]
  end
end
```

Update metadata.rb added

```
name             'app'
maintainer       'YOUR_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures app'
long_description 'Installs/Configures app'
version          '0.1.0'
```

Comment: can you paste the content of `Vagrantfile` here?

Comment: added the vagrantfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the vagrant-berkshelf plugin is outdated.

See: https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/

Answer (score 0):

Check that your app cookbook does contain a `metadata.rb` with the correct name value, and does not contain a `metadata.json`.

Comment: it doesn't contain a metdata.json and the metadata.rb is added in the original post

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the `cookbooks_path` set in your Vagrantfile, add it in `:chef_solo part` as below

```
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.custom_config_path = "Vagrantfile.chef"
    chef.cookbooks_path = "my_cookbooks"
```

Did you have cookbook path setting in `Vagrantfile.chef`? Can you confirm?

Comment: On the berkshelfs page it said 'The Chef Solo provisioner’s cookbook_path attribute is hijacked when using the Vagrant Berkshelf plugin.' When i installed this plugin the output is "The Vagrant Berkshelf plugin requires Berkshelf from the Chef Development Kit." I have the sdk installed on my machine. Also when I set my cookbook path to ~/.berkshelf/cookbooks it doesn't work

Comment: the path in `Vagrantfile` is relative path.

Comment: This isn't the solution that I'm searching for. It works, but then I need to set it in each project + my teammembers have a different path.